# mkdir variable type C++

Tags: c++

This is a part of the program I'm trying to create in C++.
Ever since starting with C++ I've had a problem with different variable types.
The function mkdir requires `const char` I believe and I'm not sure how to convert the right variable from input to what I need.

All the variables and includes required are in the program. This is my only problem.

I might not be the most specific on my problem but I'm new to C++ and any help will be appreciated, thanks!

```
int createaccount(const char acc_name)
{
     int status = mkdir("/home/person/Desktop/Accounts/" + acc_name, S_IRWXU);
     return 0;
}
```

```
std::string new_acc_name;
cin >> new_acc_name;
new_acc_namechar = str.new_acc_namechar_str();
createaccount(new_acc_namechar);`
```

Comment: what variable type is `new_acc_name`?

Comment: new_acc_name is a string

Comment: "This is my only problem."... hardly :). Your only problem is, you need to learn C++ basics (which unfortunately include C basics).

Comment: I've mastered interpreted and lightweight programming languages such as LUA and VBS for little small games, taking on C language is a whole new world for me!

Answer (score 2):

If you're working in C++, learn to use `std::string`. It is a built-in string type which can be converted to a `const char*` by calling `c_str()`. Normally you would store and pass around the `std::string` objects all the time unless you need to interface with something that takes a `const char*`. Call `c_str()` at that point. For example:

```
int createaccount(const std::string& acc_name)
{
     std::string path = "/home/person/Desktop/Accounts/" + acc_name;
     int status = mkdir(path.c_str(), S_IRWXU);
     return 0;
}
```

And after making a guess about what your code is trying to do:

```
std::string new_acc_name;
cin >> new_acc_name;
createaccount(new_acc_namechar);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int createaccount(const char acc_name)
{
     int status = mkdir("/home/person/Desktop/Accounts/" + acc_name, S_IRWXU);
     return 0;
}
```

in this function, you cannot just concatenate a `const char*` and a `char` using `+` operator. Instead you should use the `int status = mkdir (string(string("/home/person/Desktop/Accounts/")+acc_name).c_str(), S_IRWXU);`

Answer (score 1):

`mkdir()` is a libc function that is declared as (according to `man 2 mkdir`):

```
int mkdir(const char *pathname, mode_t mode);
```

so indeed, it takes a `const char*` as pathname.
In C++, you are often dealing with `std::string` rather than the low level `char*` of C. you can use both to as "strings", but they are not interchangeable.
std::string supports nice thingies like concatenating strings with the `+` operator and many more.

in your example, you are using `+` to concatenate "strings", but your strings are really char arrays, so you cannot simply concat them like that.

a simple solution would be:

```
int createaccount(const std::string&filename) {
   std::string path="/home/person/Desktop/Accounts/";
   std::string fullname=path+filename;
   int status = mkdir(fullname.c_str(), S_IRWXU); 
   return 0;
}
```

which uses std::string for concatenating and the `c_str()` member function of std::string to convert the C++-string to C's `const char*`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something along the lines of:

```
int createaccount(const char acc_name) {
    std::string combinedPath = "/home/person/Desktop/Accounts" + acc_name;
    int status = mkdir(combinedPath.c_str(), S_IRWXU);
    return status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`"/home/person/Desktop/Accounts/" + acc_name` this is adding acc_name, which is a single character, to the address of the string literal `"/home/person/Desktop/Accounts/"`. You want to do something like this.

```
int createaccount(const char acc_name)
{
  std::string dir = "/home/person/Desktop/Accounts/";
  dir += acc_name;
  int status = mkdir(dir.c_str(), S_IRWXU);
  return 0;
}
```